# Returning an object with multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python-3.x, keras, python-multiprocessing

Is this possible? I'd like to modify this to return `model`

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def get_model():
    model = load_model("./model.h5")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.99, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model # can I get this back?

# option 1: execute code with extra process
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_model)
p.start()
p.join()

# wait until user presses enter key
input()
```

(I'm trying to do this because I read that it's one solution to not being able to free my GPU memory after loading this Keras model, which ends up causing a ResourceExhaustedError later on.)

Answer (score 0):

if you load that to a global variable and keep the Memory dump i think your issue will going to be sorted.

```
`global model
model = init()
def get_model():
    model = load_model("./model.h5")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.99, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
returnt model
`
```

and after that you will be able to call the global variable in yor code.